# Unit test is running forever with Tasks

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a unit test which is running forever:

```
[Test]
public bool test()
{
    manager.Send(10);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    manager.Messages.Should().HaveCount(10);

    return true;
}
```

manager.Send() method is:

```
private void Send()
{
    try
    {
        var entities = GetAllEntities();

        foreach (var group in entities.GroupBy(r => r.Priority))
        {
            var tasks = group.Select(entity => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => manager.SendEntity(entity))).ToList();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            if (tasks.All(r => r.Result.Result == true))
            {
                // some code here...
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.FatalException(e.Message, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        logger.Info("End...");
    }
}
```

and SendEntity() method:

```
public Task<bool> SendEntity(DeferredEntity entity)
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    try
    {
        logger.Info("Sending entity {0} with params: {1}", entity.Entity, GetEntityParams(entity));

        server.SendToServer(entity, (response, result) =>
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.FatalException(e.Message, e);
    }

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

in unit test manager.Send(10) is running forever. I debuged the code and I see that the problem is in

```
if (tasks.All(r => r.Result.Result == true))
```

the debugger stops on this line and sleeps forever. What I am doing wrong? I added return value of unit test method to bool (async methods doesn't throw exceptions in void methods). But it doesn't help. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the deadlock there. 
First of all you don't have to start the new Thread with

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => manager.SendEntity(entity)
```

It seems `SendToServer` is already async.

It also a bad practice to use the `Task.Wait***/Task.Result`, use the async flow

```
private async Task Send()
{
    try
    {
        var entities = GetAllEntities();

        foreach (var group in entities.GroupBy(r => r.Priority))
        {
            var tasks = group
                .Select(entity => manager.SendEntity(entity))
                .ToArray();

            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            if (results.All(result => result))
            {
                // some code here...
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.FatalException(e.Message, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        logger.Info("End...");
    }
}
```

But if you don't want to rewrite the Send Method you can use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`

```
return taskCompletionSource.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But anyway, remove the `StartNew` - you don't need this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works! I removed StartNew and used Task.WhenAll

Comment: I'd also note that it's Bad(tm) and Evil(tm) to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run` (motivated here by stephen cleary: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)